# (python) Reshape an array (matrix) from 2D to 1D by appending next column to the previous

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to make this array:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

into an

```
([0,3,6,1,4,7,2,5,8])
```

vector?

Comment: for your requirement, transpose and flatten

Comment: your_array.reshape((1, -1))